# Is it Undefined Behavior to pass two different const character strings into std::string::insert member function?

Tags: c++, string, stl

I'm learning about STL containers now I am exploring `std::string` class.

I have a bit of confusion on the `insert` member function that takes an iterator and two const-character-strings.

Here is some sample of my code:

```
std::string str = "Hello C++ Dev";
std::string s2 = "C++ Dev";
s2.insert(s2.begin(), str.c_str(), str.c_str() + 5); // ok. or s2.insert(s2.begin(), "Hello There!", "Hello There!" + 5);
cout << s2 << endl;
s2 = "C++ Dev";

s2.insert(s2.begin(), "Hello There!", "C++ Programmer" + 5); // UB?
```

So simply is it undefined behavior to pass two different const character strings int `std::string::insert` that takes a position denoted by iterator?

- I've searched on google for some usage or explanation of this member but I didn't find any. Also [`std::basic_string<...>::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert)
  doesn't provide this version?!!

Thank you guys!

Comment: The parameters are 1) position iterator (which is at the beginning), 2) starting iterator to copy from, 3) ending iterator to copy from.  But since your ending iterator is disjoint from the starting iterator... welcome to *UB*.

Comment: That linked page does not provide that version because it does not exist. What makes you think a version taking two const character strings exists?

Comment: @JaMiT: But it does exist in `<string>` library.

Comment: `const char*` is a pointer. Pointers are iterators.

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa Where did you find documentation for this version? (Simply assuming based on reading a function signature from a header file is insufficient. For all you know it was just a specialization of #8 for when `InputIt` is `const char *`. My point being: read the comments and documentation!)

Comment: @JaMiT: Ok thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it Undefined Behavior to pass two different const character strings into std::string::insert member function?

Potentially, yes. There is at least no guarantee of well defined behaviour.

It is quite typical behaviour - and certain in case of a pointer - that the iterator to one string does not compare equal to the iterator to the other string before the algorithm has iterated beyond the bounds of the range of the iterated range, which will have undefined behaviour (buffer overflow) in case of most iterators (and certainly in case of bare pointers).

> Also [`std::basic_string<...>::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert) doesn't provide this version?!!

Yes it does. It's this one:

> ```
> template< class InputIt >
> iterator insert( const_iterator pos, InputIt first, InputIt last );
> ```

Comment: Thank you! Now I get it.

Answer (score 2):

You are using insertion *by range*. Its overall syntax is as follows:

```
template <class InputIterator> iterator insert (iterator p, InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
```

> Is it Undefined Behavior to pass two different const character strings into std::string::insert member function?

Yes, it is UB. For this function to work as expected, both iterators must point to the same string.

Think these iterators as pointers. The 'insert' function will try to insert every character found from the character pointed by 'first' to the character pointed by 'last'. If they point to different strings, you don't really know what you are really coping. In fact you don't even know if the 'first' pointer actually points to a position before that pointed by 'last'.